# 're-sort' / adapt ticks of matshow matrix plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried hard, but I'm stuck with matplotlib here. Please overlook, that the mpl docs are a bit confusing to me . My question concerns the following:

1. I draw a symmetrical n*n matrix `D` with `matshow` function. That works.
2. I want to do the same thing, just with different order of (the n) items in `D`

   ```
   D = [:,neworder]
   D = [neworder,:]
   ```

Now, how do I make the ticks reproduce this neworder, preferably using additionally `MaxNLocator`?

As far as I understand...

`set_xticklabels` assigns labels to the ticks by order, independently of where the ticks are set?!
`set_xticks` (mpl docs: 'Set the x ticks with list of ticks') here I'm really not sure what it does. Can somebody explain it precisely? I don't know, whether these functions are helpful in my case at all. Maybe even things are different between using a common xy plot and matshow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

D = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)

neworder = np.arange(10)
np.random.shuffle(neworder)

D = D[:,neworder]
D = D[neworder, :]

# modify ticks somehow...

ax.matshow(D)
plt.show()
```

Referring to Paul's answer, think I tried smth like this. Using the `neworder` to define positions and using it for the labels, I added `plt.xticks(neworder, neworder)` as tick-modifier. For example with `neworder = [9 8 4 7 2 6 3 0 1 5]` I get is this
 [image: correct order, but incorrect ticks]
The order of the labels is correct, but the ticks are not. The labels should be independently show the correct element independently of *where* the ticks are set. So where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is set the labels on the new plot to show the rearranged order of the values.  Is that right?  If so, you want to keep the tick *locations* the same, but change the *labels*:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,10), neworder)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10), neworder)
```

**Edit:**  Note that these commands must be issued *after* `matshow`.  This seems to be a quirk of `matshow` (`plot` does not show this behaviour, for example).  Perhaps it's related to this line from the plt.matshow documentation:

> Because of how :func:`matshow` tries to set the figure aspect ratio to be the
>     one of the array, if you provide the number of an already
>     existing figure, strange things may happen.

Perhaps the safest way to go is to issue `plt.matshow(D)` without first creating a figure, then use `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks` to make adjustments.

Your question also asks about the `set_ticks` and related `axis` methods.  The same thing can be accomplished using those tools, again *after* issuing `matshow`:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,10))  # turn on all tick locations
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(neworder)    # use neworder for labels
```

**Edit2:**  The next part of your question is related to setting a max number of ticks.  20 would require a new example.  For our example I'll set the max no. of ticks at 2:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(nbins=3))  # one less tick than 'bin'
tl = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()                          # get current tick locations
tl[1:-1] = [neworder[idx] for idx in tl[1:-1]]        # find what the labels should be at those locs
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(tl)                           # set the labels
plt.draw()
```

Comment: the problem is, it gives me 5 ticks still (like x axis on the pic). while handing [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], the ticks are set at [0,2,4,6,8] showing neworder[1:5] as labels. i need it to show 10 ticks, or if 5, then labelling it neworder[0,2,4,6,8]...

Comment: @talkturkey: I see the same behaviour when going through your example from scratch.  In ipython, I don't see the actual map until I issue `plt.draw()` (`plt.show()` doesn't cut it).  Then the axes need to be re-ticked with the above two commands.  Edited my answer to reflect this.  Can you confirm that works for you?

Comment: First problem is solved. Indeed it was just, that I put the tick-modification _before_ `matshow`. Now is it possible to combine this with a locator so that e. g. max 20 ticks are shown with _correct_ labelling?

Comment: @talkturkey: Of course!  All is possible.  `:-)` See further edit.

Comment: Works perfectly. So to '`get_ticklocs`' and to reassign the labels is the trick. I don't fully grasp why the ticks `tl[0]` and `tl[-1]` are outside the map, but knowing it I can take it into account

Comment: Just when zooming in, depending on number of elements, it re-sets the ticks. Then they are again not proper anymore. But I guess mastering this is a bit more complicated, cause one would need to know which elements are in the zoomed area. So, I can do without..

Comment: The problem I encountered now in your solution is the `tl`. Somehow, even with xlim set, it gives indices out of `neworder`s range , thus throws an exception. I tried to cut the `tl` but its cumbersome and it didn't work neither.

Comment: Well, given the example above, you would definitely need to have the no. of ticks <= the no. of elements in neworder.  If you're doing something new, I suggest asking a new question with a different example.

Comment: I think the point is xlim will not limit the ticklocks (for formatting reasons). I clip now the x in the `FuncFormatter` function `FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: neworder[int(np.clip(x, 0, len(neworder)-1))])`. Ticks will be set correctly even after zooming

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  The plt.xticks command is what you need.

You can specify the xtick locations and the label at each position with the following command.
    labelPositions = arange(len(D))
    newLabels = ['z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','q','r']
    plt.xticks(labelPositions,newLabels)

You could also specify an arbitrary order for labelPositions, as they will be assigned based on the values in the vector.

```
labelPositions = [0,9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5]
newLabels = ['z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','q','r']
plt.xticks(labelPositions,newLabels)
```